# excluding count from dataFrame if value is 0

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the code below:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
# Read data from file 'filename.csv' 
# (in the same directory that your python process is based)
# Control delimiters, rows, column names with read_csv (see later) 
df = pd.read_csv("../example.csv", parse_dates=['DateTime']) 
# Preview the first 5 lines of the loaded data 



df = df.assign(Burned = df['Quantity'])
df.loc[df['To'] != '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'Burned'] = 0.0
# OR:

df['cum_sum'] = df['Burned'].cumsum()
df['percent_burned'] = df['cum_sum']/df['Quantity'].max()*100.0

per_day           =    df.groupby(df['DateTime'].dt.date)['Burned'].count().reset_index(name='Trx')
```

The last line create a dataFrame called per_day which sorts all the transactions by day from the df dataFrame. Many of the transactions from df have 'Burned' = 0. I want to count the total number of transactions which is what my current code does. But I want to exclude transactions in which 'Burned'=0.

Also, how can I consoladate these 3 lines of code? I don't even want to create per_day_burned. How do I just make this its own column in per_day without doing it the way I did it?

```
per_day           =    dg.groupby(dg['DateTime'].dt.date)['Burned'].count().reset_index(name='Trx')
per_day_burned    =    dg.groupby(dg['DateTime'].dt.date)['Burned'].sum().reset_index(name='Burned') 
per_day['Burned'] = per_day_burned['Burned']
```

Comment: `df = df[df['Burned'] != 0]

Comment: @Aryerez Can you look at the second part of my question too? I just added it